# Mysql SELECT ASC without last 50 rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say I have 1000 rows in a database and I want to display 950 of it.
The rows I want to display should be the first 950 without the last 50. So how can I protect the last 50 rows?
Something like this query but I would like to start with ASC to select the rows from the beggining not from the end.

```
$tab= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id,title,url FROM users ORDER by id DESC limit 50,950");
```

What I need is 1,2,4,5...950 from 1000 rows ( without the last $limit rows). I will change the $limit,950 depending when I need it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you delete where id < xxx ?

Comment: @RGriffiths: Obviously not since almost all ID sequences contain gaps due to deleted records

Comment: I have 15 milions rows and every day I have my db updated. I would like to start from 1,2,3,4....14 mil. without the last 1 milion rows. Also I want to change the $limit,1000 every time I want.

Comment: But you have them in order of id. I should have said delete where id > xxx but either way I am not sure what the problem is. Pick the highest id you want to keep and delete all the ones higher.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does allow `LIMIT` in the `DELETE`.  But, I don't believe it allows an offset.  This is easily handled by reversing the order:

```
DELETE u
    FROM users u
    ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 950;
```

You can also write this more directly incorporating your original query:

```
DELETE u
    FROM users u JOIN
         (SELECT u2.*
          FROM users u2
          ORDER BY u2.id DESC
          LIMIT 50, 950
         ) todelete
         ON u.id = todelete.id;
```

Comment: The delete is not a problem because I delete the rows using jquery after I display all the results. What I want is to select the first rows without the last 50.  50 and 1000 are for example. I have milions of rows in my db and I will change the $limit each time I need. So what I need is SELECT * from db ORDER by id ASC (without the last $limit rows). I mentioned the delete in the topic and now maybe is confusing. Sorry. What I want is to display the rows I want to delete

Comment: @paulb . . . Then the subquery in the second query does what you want.

Comment: That will not order the rows DESC without the last 50? I want to order all the rows ASC without the last 50